# Maven should not increment project version

Tags: maven

Is there an option or plugin in **maven** which will keep the project version the same? I have looked at the versions plugin but that did not have that option.

Right now, it updates the project's version number from say
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ==> 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.

Is there a way to keep the the version the same?
(The reason is that I want do some post build updates to the pom but do not want to necessarily update the project version number)

Thank you.

Comment: Under which circumstances would like to helt the versions number the same? Have you made an release via release plugin? The Updates looks like you are working with release plugin? What kind of post build updates do you like to do?

Comment: updating the dependency versions to SNAPSHOT versions without creating a new snapshot version. I have ended up using post build steps to take care of that now.

Answer (score 3):

Normally maven doesn't do that. You are probably using [autoincrement-versions-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/autoincrement-versions-maven-plugin/). Remove it from your pom.xml and it should stop. If it is not the issue then add your pom.xml files to your post please.

Answer (score 3):

Just tell the release plugin to keep the version the same, e.g.

```
mvn -B -DreleaseVersion=0.0.1.7 -DdevelopmentVersion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

and next release

```
mvn -B -DreleaseVersion=0.0.1.8 -DdevelopmentVersion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

The downside is that you need to remember what versions you have released.

The up side is this works really well for continuous deployment via a CI system (e.g. jenkins)

So for example you might set up a Jenkins nightly job that runs

```
mvn -B -DreleaseVersion=0.1.$BUILD_NUMBER -DdevelopmentVersion=0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

That will let your developers stay on a nice SNAPSHOT while releases run thereafter.

A fancy bit of shell scripting could extract the current version from the pom and replace -SNAPSHOT with `.$BUILD_NUMBER` and then invoke maven with that version to give a constant going forward solution... but this is left as an exercise to the reader